# Saving object to file on internal storage (Android)

Tags: android, serialization

I tried this:

```
public class People implements Serializable  {

String name;

public People(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void saveAsObject(People p) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    try 
    {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("test","test.dat") ));
        os.writeObject(p);
        os.close();
        System.out.println("Sucess");
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

}
```

I created that folder manually. It throws this eror: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /test/test.txt: open failed: ENOENT" (No such file or directory)

When i tried

```
 new FileOutputStream("text.dat")
```

it throws java.io.FileNotFoundException: EROFS (Read only file system)

This is my main class:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            People p = new People("Ray");
    try {
        p.saveAsObject(p);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15067968/1531054

Comment: Thank you, i will try Context.getFilesDir ().

Answer (score 1):

this `new File("test","test.dat")` is not a valid way of getting a file path on Android.

try this:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/data.dat");
```

Comment: I would like to save it on internal storage, could I use Environment.getDataDirectory() instead?

Comment: from the activity you can call `getCacheDir()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your app's default current working directory is "/", which you won't have permission to write to.